# running rspec with "-e" parameter

Tags: ruby, rspec

I can run the simple ruby program like

```
ruby -e "puts 'raja'"
```

but when I run Rspec file, I run this way

```
ruby rspec my_example_spec.rb
```

Said that, Do I have any way to pass the rspec program as parameter as I have done in the first line?

I tried

```
ruby -e rspec "require 'rspec'
require 'watir'
describe 'My behaviour' do
  it 'should do something' do
    b = Watir::Browser.new
    b.goto 'www.google.com'
    b.text_field(name: 'q').set 'Rajagopalan'
    sleep 2
    b.close
  end
end"
```

But it's not running. How can I pass rspec program with '-e' parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling a bit, I found this issue thread on the RSpec github: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/359

It seems you can run your RSpec tests from Ruby by putting

```
RSpec::Core::Runner::run({}, $stderr, $stdout)
```

after your definitions.

The following minimal test works for me:

```
ruby -e "require 'rspec'
describe 'My behaviour' do
  it 'should do something' do
    expect(1).to eq(2)
  end
end
RSpec::Core::Runner::run({}, \$stderr, \$stdout)
"
```

Comment: Hi, May I know why you put \ infront of $stderr and $stdout?

Comment: Because it's a shell script, otherwise bash will think those are shell variables you're interpolating.

Comment: Try this to see `x=1; ruby -e "puts $x"`

Comment: I am getting this error
`W:\>x=1; ruby -e "puts $x"
'x' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Rajagopalan ok, you're on Windows (not bash). But my point is that unintended things happen when you don't escape it.